# jQuery stop function in setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

How to stop the execution of firstShow after each Interval.I want it to begin from 0.

```
var firstShow = function(){

             $("#i_can").delay(2000).fadeIn(300);

            $( "#me" ).delay( 4000).fadeIn( 300 );

            $( "#horizons" ).delay( 6000 ).fadeIn(300);

              .....      

        }

    firstShow()   
    var NewTextAgain = setInterval(firstShow,10000)
```

Comment: Its not clear. What do you mean by `begin from 0`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5dvfa7ow/16/ this function repeats on and on, but on the 6th time the text starts to overlap. How can I manage this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this using callback function, that it will fire the function again only after completing all the effects

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#i_can").hide();
  $("#me").hide();
  $("#horizons").hide();
  $("#team").hide();
  $("#grow").hide();
  $("#course").hide();
  $("#celebrate").hide();

  var i;
  var test = function() {
    i++;
    if (i == 14) firstShow();
  }

  var firstShow = function() {
    i = 0;
    $("#i_can").delay(2000).fadeIn(300, test);
    $("#me").delay(4000).fadeIn(300, test);
    $("#horizons").delay(6000).fadeIn(300, test);
    $("#me").delay(4000).fadeOut(test);
    $("#horizons").delay(2000).fadeOut(test);
    $("#team").delay(10000).fadeIn(300, test);
    $("#course").delay(12000).fadeIn(300, test);
    $("#team").delay(4000).fadeOut(test);
    $("#course").delay(2000).fadeOut(test);
    $("#grow").delay(16000).fadeIn(300, test);
    $("#celebrate").delay(18000).fadeIn(test);
    $("#grow").delay(5200).fadeOut(test);
    $("#celebrate").delay(3100).fadeOut(test);
    $("#i_can").delay(19200).fadeOut(test);
  }
  firstShow();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 style="text-align: center;visiblility:hidden;font-family: Titillium Web" id="i_can" class="i_can">I can</h2>
<h2 style="text-align: center;visiblility:hidden;font-family: Titillium Web" id="me">Challenge Myself</h2>
<h2 style="text-align: center;visiblility:hidden;font-family: Titillium Web" id="horizons"> To Chart New Horizons</h2>
<h2 style="text-align: center;visiblility:hidden;font-family: Titillium Web" id="team"> Challenge My Team</h2>
<h2 style="text-align: center;visiblility:hidden;font-family: Titillium Web" id="course"> To Set New Courses</h2>
<h2 style="text-align: center;visiblility:hidden;font-family: Titillium Web" id="grow">Grow With You</h2>
<h2 style="text-align: center;visiblility:hidden;font-family: Titillium Web" id="celebrate">To Celebrate Success</h2>
```

Comment: @user4523851 : glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You are should hide the elements on each iteration

```
var firstShow = function() {
  $("#i_can, #me, #horizons").hide();
  $("#i_can").delay(2000).fadeIn(300);
  $("#me").delay(4000).fadeIn(300);
  $("#horizons").delay(6000).fadeIn(300);
}

firstShow();
var NewTextAgain = setInterval(firstShow, 10000);
```

[Working example](http://codepen.io/etumyan/pen/xGNqyN?editors=111)